# Prove that every group of order $49$ contains a subgroup of order $7$.

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

Prove that every group of order $49$ contains a subgroup of order $7$.

We know that a group of prime order is always cyclic. Also, we know that if the order of a group is $pq$, where $p,q$ are prime integers, then a subgroup $H\neq G$ is a cyclic subgroup. But here in this question, we don’t know whether such a non-trivial  subgroup $H$ of $G$ exists. If it would have existed, then we could have said, by Lagrange’s theorem, that the subgroup has an order of $7$ and hence $H$ is cyclic. But such an information is not given. So how do we prove it? I am not quite getting it . . . Also, there might be posts concerning the similar topic on this site but I can’t seem to find it either . . .

Comment: I strongly suspect that this is a duplicate but do not see a duplicated question offhand. In any case, what are the possible orders of an element of a group of $49$?

Comment: Hint: let $x\neq e$ be any element. Its order divides $49$, so...

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**

Cauchy's theorem ensures an element of order $7$.

Since you don't know Cauchy, we do the following:  Either the group is cyclic,  in which case it contains a subgroup of every order dividing the order of the group;  or it contains an element of order $7$. (Of course we used Lagrange.)

---

Alternative: every group of order $p^2$ is abelian.   Thus by the structure theorem,  either we have $\Bbb Z_{49}$ or $\Bbb Z_7×\Bbb Z_7$.

Comment: Actually, I am still learning elementary group theory so I don't quite know about Cauchy's theorem...

Comment: Do you know Sylow?

Comment: Sorry ! But no ...This was a problem given as an excercise concerning cosets and Lagrange's theorem on a group theory book ...

Comment: Forget Sylow.  Take a nontrivial element.  It's order divides $49$.  If it's $49$ the group is cyclic.   And we're done.  If it's $7$, we're also done.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I do get it now! Thank you!...

Comment: While the answer itself is fine, the indication that it mimics the proof of Cauchy's theorem is misleading.

Comment: Yeah I guess that's an exaggeration.   I meant the proof of Cauchy that uses Sylow's theorem.  But it was over quite quickly (although the proof I'm referring to is also quite short).  @TobiasKildetoft

Answer (score 3):

Every nontrivial element of $G$ has order $7$ or $49$ (Lagrange). In the former case, you are done. In the second case, say $x$ an element of order $49$; then, the element $x^7$ has order $7$.